# Selecting child element that shares class in different sibling

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

Okay, so I'm sort of incorporating indexing more into my code, and the first example works fine. What it is, is I have elements in different parent containers that I've had to use indexing for to find them across various positions in the DOM. I've had to add empty siblings of the parent element in the first example to match the indexing to my array - the second item in the array of the first function is exempt from the function, because I need to animate the height property to a lesser height.

So instead, I made the second function to find the child element `"div.up"` to the parent element `"div.listitem1"`, I have 3 divs with the same class name for formatting purposes but different IDs (listemitem #1, #2, #3 etc).

Just wondering if there's a way I can create a conditional statement for the `div.up` element in the first function rather than trying to go through the DOM in the second function and try to reduce to coding. The reason I've got the same element in the first array for the second function is purely because I've got boosted indexes that should only be working on the second half of the array.

```
$(function(){
  var arr = [ "div.mainarticle", "div.listitem1", "div.article1", "div.article2",];

  $("div.up").parent().on("mouseleave", function(index){
    var k= $(this).index();
    var height=$("div.up").find("p").height();

    $(arr[k]).find("div.up").animate({'height':'-=20%'}, 300).find("p").fadeOut();
    $(this).find("span.date").animate({'top':'-=' + height +'px'});;
  });
});

$(function(){
  var divup = ["div.up", "div.up", "div.up", "div.up", "div.up", "div.up",]

  $("div.itemlist1").on("mouseenter", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    $(index[divup]).find("div.up");
    $(this).animate({'height':'+=80px'});
  });
});
```

Is indexing the best way to link elements together? Like, is that something that's common in programming across the board? I was thinking probably because it's all numbers and that and computers like numbers.

Comment: Just to be clear, by `index[divup]` you instead mean `divup[index]`, right?! But indeed, i don't get the logic behind your code. You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue. And maybe, i completly misundertsand your question

Comment: Okay, so I'd like the animation function to run on children of a different parent but I want to say if the height of the div (div.up) to animate up is like than a certain height then animate to different height.

Comment: Really sounds like a XY problem. Again, you should provide jsFiddle/code snippet replicating your issue.

Comment: Okay, here it is, writing to the index to list at the top for testing.

https://jsfiddle.net/wrgvm0x3/1/